# `<=': comparison of Integer with String failed (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, conversão-de-tipo

Eu quero saber a idade, ai fiz o seguinte Código:

```
nascimento = "12/34/5678"
dia =  nascimento[0,2]
mes =  nascimento[3,2]
ano =  nascimento[6,4]
dia.to_i
mes.to_i
ano.to_i
age = 2020 - 2000 #ano atual menos ano do usuario
if 8 <= mes && 14<dia #verifico se o mes atual é menor do mes do aniversariante e se o dia atual é menor que o mes dito pelo usuario
    age-=1 
end


puts dia
puts mes
puts ano
puts "Age #{age}"
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro:

> <=': comparison of Integer with String failed (ArgumentError)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Você não guardou o valor convertido para inteiro em lugar algum, então é feito a conversão e o resultado é jogado fora e a variável continua sendo uma *string*.

O ideal é fazer a conversão de vez, assim já cria a variável do tipo que ela deve ser. Esse é um dos problemas que linguagens de tipagem dinâmica traz.

Não vou fazer um teste se a conversão deu certo porque o dado é explícito e não vem de fora, se viesse precisa verificar se deu certo. Por outro lado, como o dado é conhecido não faz muito sentido um código complexo. Entendo que é só um exercício, mas ou faz algo real ou faz algo simples, essa forma dá impressão que assim é o correto de fazer.

Tem outros problemas no cálculo que resolvi não mexer.

```
nascimento = "12/34/5678"
dia =  nascimento[0,2].to_i
mes =  nascimento[3,2].to_i
ano =  nascimento[6,4].to_i
age = 2020 - 2000
if 8 <= mes && 14 < dia
    age -= 1 
end
puts dia
puts mes
puts ano
puts "Age #{age}"
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nzm3Wz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lrywpnpr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Conversion.rb).